# Interacting with JButton in Java

Tags: java

I have a project that has an interface I'm supposed to make with three classes: Flight, Ticket and Seat. When the user clicks on the seat, the button is highlighted in blue and the "Seat" text field is filled with seat number. Once the user clicks on the "Choose seat" button, the button is highlighted in red and message pops up asking the user if he wants to confirm the procedure.

PS: There are 100 seats which means there are 100 buttons . The rows are labeled in numbers up to 20 and rows are labeled in A,B,C,D and E.

My questions are:

1. I tried for loop to multiply the number of buttons and labels but it didn't work.  How can I change the color of the buttons once I click the button or when I click another button?
2. How can I link the "Seat" text field with the seat buttons in a way that shows the seat number?

EDIT: After changing my code and trying to use different codes It's still difficult for me to change the color of the seat buttons.
Here is my code.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.* ; 
import java.io.* ; 
class project extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{ 
Flight  flight = new Flight("Emirates", 817 ,  "RUH-DXB" , 1.45 , 18.3 ) ;
Seat  tempSeat , seat  ; 
JButton tempButton ;  
int ticketNO = 1  ;
String TicketNo ;  // to keep like "TK00001" 
boolean issu = false ; 
String resultTicket = "" ; 

private JLabel label1 ; 
private JLabel label2 ; 
private JLabel label3 ; 
private JLabel label4 ; 
private JLabel label5 ; 
private JLabel label6 ; 
private JLabel label7 ; 
private JLabel label8 ; 
private JLabel label9 ; 

private JButton chooseButton;
private JButton IssueButton;

private JTextField inputLine1;
private JTextField inputLine2;
private JTextField inputLine3;
private JTextField inputLine4;
private JTextField inputLine5;
private JTextField inputLine6;
private JTextField inputLine7;
private JTextField inputLine8;


private JTextArea  textArea ; 

// 2D array 

JButton[][]  LButton = new JButton[20][5];

// inner class to invoke the close window event
class EventHandler extends WindowAdapter 
 {

    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent evt) {

     int answer = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null , "Are you sure that you want to Exit ?"
        ,"Exit", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

     if( answer == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
     {

        Date date = new Date() ; 
        try 
        {
           File outFile = new File("Log.txt") ; 
           FileOutputStream sf = new FileOutputStream(outFile) ; 
           PrintWriter pf = new PrintWriter(sf) ;


           pf.println("=================" ) ; 
           pf.println("Today's Log - + " +  date.toString()+"\n" );
           pf.println("Issued Tickets: ");

           for(int i = 0 ; i< resultTicket.length() ; i++)
           {
              if( resultTicket.charAt(i) != '\n' )
                 pf.print(resultTicket.charAt(i));    // same text in textArea
              else
                 pf.println();
           }


           pf.println("The airlines of the flight: " + flight.getairLines() );
           pf.println("Flight number: " + flight.getflightNo());
           pf.println("Route: "+ flight.getroute() );
           pf.println("Departure Time: " + flight.getDepartureTime());
           pf.println("Dutation: " + flight.getduration());

           for(int r = 0 ; r < 20 ; r++)
           {
              for(int c = 0 ; c < 5 ; c++)
              {
                 pf.print( flight.list[r][c].getSeatNo() + " : " );
                 pf.println( flight.list[r][c].isAvailable() ? "Available" : "Unavailable");
              }
           }
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null , "The information is/are saved");
           pf.close() ; 
           System.exit(0) ; 

        } // end try
        catch(IOException e  )
        {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null , "Error, file couldn't be opened");
           System.exit(0) ; 

        }

     } // end if answer
  }
  }// end inner class 
   //---------------------------------------


  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
  project frame = new project();
  frame.setVisible(true);    

  }

  public project() { 

  addWindowListener(new EventHandler());   


  Container contentPane = getContentPane( );
  setSize      (900, 700);
  setResizable (false);
  setTitle     ("Seat Selector ");
  setLocation  (200, 10);
  contentPane.setLayout(null);

  label1 = new JLabel("AirLines:" ) ; 
  label1. setBounds(10 , 30 , 100 , 30 ) ; 
  contentPane.add(label1 );

  inputLine1 = new JTextField(flight.getairLines());
  inputLine1.setColumns(10);
  inputLine1. setBounds(80 , 30 , 150 , 30 ) ; 
  inputLine1.setEnabled(false);
  contentPane.add(inputLine1 );


  label2 = new JLabel("FlightNumber:" ) ; 
  label2. setBounds(250 , 30 , 100 , 30 ) ; 
  contentPane.add(label2 );

  inputLine2 = new JTextField("" + flight.getflightNo());
  inputLine2.setColumns(10);
  inputLine2. setBounds(340 , 30 , 150 , 30 ) ; 
  inputLine2.setEnabled(false);
  contentPane.add(inputLine2 );

   //=================================

  label3 = new JLabel("Rout:" ) ; 
  label3. setBounds(10 , 60 , 100 , 30 ) ; 
  contentPane.add(label3 );

  inputLine3 = new JTextField(flight.getroute());
  inputLine3.setColumns(10);
  inputLine3. setBounds(80 , 60 , 150 , 30 ) ;
  inputLine3.setEnabled(false);
  contentPane.add(inputLine3 );


  label4 = new JLabel("Duration:" ) ; 
  label4. setBounds(250 , 60 , 100 , 30 ) ; 
  contentPane.add(label4 );

  inputLine4 = new JTextField(""+flight.getduration());
  inputLine4.setColumns(10);
  inputLine4. setBounds(340 , 60 , 150 , 30 ) ; 
  inputLine4.setEnabled(false);
  contentPane.add(inputLine4 );
   //=======================================

  label5 = new JLabel("TicketNubmer:" ) ; 
  label5. setBounds(10 , 120 , 100 , 30 ) ; 
  contentPane.add(label5 );

  inputLine5 = new JTextField("TK0000" + ticketNO);
  inputLine5.setColumns(10);
  inputLine5. setBounds(10 , 150 , 150 , 30 ) ; 
  inputLine1.setEnabled(false);
  contentPane.add(inputLine5 );


  label6 = new JLabel("Departure Time:" ) ; 
  label6. setBounds(250 , 90 , 100 , 30 ) ; 
  contentPane.add(label6 );

  inputLine6 = new JTextField("" + flight.getDepartureTime());
  inputLine6.setColumns(10);
  inputLine6. setBounds(340 , 90 , 150 , 30 ) ; 
  inputLine6.setEnabled(false);
  contentPane.add(inputLine6 );
  //=======================================
  label7 = new JLabel("Pasenger:" ) ; 
  label7. setBounds(10 , 190 , 100 , 30 ) ; 
  contentPane.add(label7 );

  inputLine7 = new JTextField("Passenger Name");
  inputLine7.setColumns(10);
  inputLine7. setBounds(80 , 190 , 150 , 30 ) ; 
  contentPane.add(inputLine7 ); 

  chooseButton= new JButton("Choose Seat");
  chooseButton. setBounds(250 , 190 , 150 , 30 ) ; 
  contentPane.add(chooseButton) ;
  chooseButton.addActionListener(this);
  //====================================

  label8 = new JLabel("Seat:" ) ; 
  label8. setBounds(10 , 230 , 100 , 30 ) ; 
  contentPane.add(label8 );
  inputLine8 = new JTextField();
  inputLine8.setColumns(10);
  inputLine8. setBounds(80 , 230 , 70 , 30 ) ; 
  inputLine8.setEnabled(false);
  contentPane.add(inputLine8 ); 

  IssueButton= new JButton("Issue Ticket");
  IssueButton. setBounds(250 , 230 , 150 , 30 ) ; 
  contentPane.add(IssueButton) ;
  IssueButton.addActionListener(this);


  label9 = new JLabel("Today's Log:" ) ; 
  label9. setBounds(30 , 370 , 150 , 30 ) ; 
  contentPane.add(label9 );

  textArea = new JTextArea();
  textArea.setColumns(15);
  textArea.setRows(8);
  textArea.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));
  textArea.setEditable(false);
  textArea. setBounds(30 , 400 , 400 , 200 ) ; 
  contentPane.add(textArea); 

  //==========================
  JLabel  chr[] = new JLabel[5];
  char ch = 'A' ;
  int x = 600 ; 
  int  y = 20 ;  
  for(int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++)
  {
     chr[i] = new JLabel(""+ch++) ; 
     chr[i].setBounds(x , y , 20 , 20 ) ; 
     contentPane.add(chr[i] );
     x += 20 ; 
  }
  //=============================
  JLabel  No[] = new JLabel[20];
  x = 580 ; 
  y = 40 ;  
  for(int i = 0 ; i < 20 ; i++)
  {
     No[i] = new JLabel(""+(i+1)) ; 
     No[i].setBounds(x , y , 20 , 20 ) ; 
     contentPane.add(No[i] );
     y += 20 ; 
  }


   //========================
  x = 600 ; 
  y = 20 ;
  for(int i = 0 ; i < 20 ; i++)
  {
     y = y + 20 ; 
     x = 600 ; 
     for(int j = 0 ; j<5; j++)
     {

        LButton[i][j] = new JButton();
        LButton[i][j]. setBounds(x , y , 20 , 20 ) ; 
        contentPane.add( LButton[i][j]) ;
        LButton[i][j].setBackground(Color.GREEN) ; 
        LButton[i][j].addActionListener(this);
        x = x+20 ; 

     }
  }
  disAbleSeat() ;   // call method to make all seat color unEnable 

  setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );


   //////////***************************************
   // load file
   /*
   Seat list[]= null ;  
  try
   {
  File f = new File("reservedSeat.dat") ; 
  FileInputStream r = new FileInputStream(f) ; 
  ObjectInputStream  file = new ObjectInputStream (r) ; 

  list = (Seat[]) file.readObject() ; 
  file.close() ; 
  }
 catch(ClassNotFoundException  e)
 {
 System.out.println("Error, class not found");
 System.exit(0) ; 
 }
 catch(IOException  e)
 {
 System.out.println("Error, file couldn't be opened ");
 System.exit(0) ; 
 }


 for(int k = 0 ; k < list.length ; k++)
 {
 for(int i = 0 ; i < 20 ; i++)
for(int j = 0 ; j< 5 ; j++)
{
Seat s = flight.getSeat(i,j) ;
if( list[i].getSeatNo().equals( s.getSeatNo()))
{
s.setAvailable(false);
LButton[i][j].setBackground(Color.RED)  ;   
}

   }
   }
   /////////////////////////////////////////*****
   */

  }// end constructor

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

  JButton press = (JButton) event.getSource() ; 
  String str = press.getText() ; 

  if(str.equals("Choose Seat") ) 
  {
     chooseButton.setText("Confirm");
     enableSeat() ; 
     TicketNo = "TK" + ( ticketNO < 9 ? "0000" : "000") + ticketNO ; 
     inputLine5.setText(TicketNo) ; 
     return ;  
  }
  else
     if(str.equals("Confirm"))
     {
        if( tempSeat == null && tempButton == null  ) 
        {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this , "first select seat.");
           return ; 
        }
        else
           if( issu == true )
           {
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this , "you are already confirm issue seat");
              return ; 
           }
           else
           {
              tempSeat.setAvailable(false) ; 
              tempButton.setBackground(Color.RED);
              issu = true ; 
              disAbleSeat() ; 
              return ;  
           }

     } // end confirm 
  if(str.equals("Issue Ticket"))
  {
     if( issu == false )
     {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this , "you can not creat a Ticket without        confirming a seat ");
        return ; 
     }
     else
     {
        int answer = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null , "are you sure you want to issue the thicket?"
           ,"confirming", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

        if( answer == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
        {

           Ticket tick = new Ticket(inputLine7.getText() , 
                         TicketNo , flight , tempSeat   ) ; 

           ticketNO++ ; 
           tick.issueTicket() ; 
           chooseButton.setText("Choose Seat");
           resultTicket += tick.getticketNo() +"-"+ tick.getpassenger()+"-"+tempSeat.getSeatNo() +"\n" ; 
           textArea.append (tick.getticketNo() +"-"+ tick.getpassenger()+"-"+tempSeat.getSeatNo() +"\n" ); 
           tempSeat = null ;
           tempButton = null ;   
        }// press yes 
        else
           if( answer == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)     // cancel seat and return seat to grean color
           {
              chooseButton.setText("Choose Seat");
              tempButton.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
              tempSeat.setAvailable(true) ; 

              disAbleSeat() ; 

              tempSeat = null ;
              tempButton = null ;
           }// press no 
     } // end if issu 
     issu = false ; 

  }// end button issue
  //====================================================
  else    // if press seat buttons
  {
     if( tempSeat != null && tempButton != null  ) 
     {
        tempButton.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        tempSeat = null ; 
        tempButton = null ; 
     }

     for(int i = 0 ; i < 20 ; i++)
     {
        for(int j = 0 ; j<5; j++)
        {
           if(press == LButton[i][j] )
           {
              seat = flight.getSeat(i,j) ; 

              if(seat.isAvailable() == false ) 
                 return ; 

              tempSeat = seat ; 
              tempButton = press ; 
              press.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
              inputLine8.setText(seat.getSeatNo());
              return ;           
           }

        } // end for j 
     }// end for i 
  }//  end press  seat buttons 



   }// end Action

  public void enableSeat() // all avalable 
   {
     for(int i = 0 ; i < 20 ; i++)
     for(int j = 0 ; j<5; j++)
        LButton[i][j].setEnabled(true) ; 
   }

   public void disAbleSeat() // 
   {
  for(int i = 0 ; i < 20 ; i++)
     for(int j = 0 ; j<5; j++)
        LButton[i][j].setEnabled(false) ; 
   }

 }// end class
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a MouseListener to handle click events on JButtons. Then, inside the listener, use `this` to access the button, and change its values. From it, you can access the other objects, assuming you developed those relationships in the Classes.

Another way is to use singleton pattern to load all components, then call them in your listener when you need them. Thus, they must be accessible from the event handler method.

Well, for the rest of your question, that's general application design, so that's pretty complicated to answer as different people may do things differently (some good designs, some poor ones, depending on the context)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you as a starting point

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ListButtonPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private List<JButton> buttons = new ArrayList<>();

    public ListButtonPanel() {

        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1024, 768));
        for(int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            buttons.add(new JButton("Seat-" + i));
        }

        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 10));
        for(JButton button : buttons) {
            button.addActionListener(this);
            this.add(button);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JButton sourceBtn = (JButton) e.getSource();

        int showConfirmDialog = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(getParent(), "You want to reserve seat " + sourceBtn.getText() + "", "Reserve Seat", JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION);

        if(showConfirmDialog == 0) {
            sourceBtn.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED, 3, true));
            sourceBtn.setEnabled(false);
            sourceBtn.setForeground(Color.red);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two java classes demonstrating the basic concepts you need:

The first one shows how to create buttons in a for loop and add an ActionListener for the click event.

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Frame extends JFrame {

    public Frame() {
        setSize(600, 400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));

        JTextField field = new JTextField();

        // batch create buttons
        JButton btn;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            String name = new Integer(i+1).toString();
            btn = new JButton(name);

            // add an action command to identify the buttons
            btn.setActionCommand(name);

            // add an instance of Action to handle the click event
            btn.addActionListener(new Action(field));

            // add button to the frame
            add(btn);
        }

        // add the field to the frame
        add(field);

        pack();

        setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

The second one implements the ActionEvent and shows how to manipulate a textfield and color the clicked button.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Action implements ActionListener {

    public JTextField field;

    public Action(JTextField theField) {
        field = theField;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // set the textfield's text
        field.setText(e.getActionCommand());

        // set clicked button color
        JButton theButton = (JButton)e.getSource();
        theButton.setBackground(new Color(255, 0, 0));
    }

}
```